# Can cherrypy handle say 5,000 requests a minute for an eCommerce website?

Tags: cherrypy

I know this question is one step above 'how can I speed up my website' but I've looked around at sites powered by cherrypy and didn't find any eCommerce sites.  We began working on a demo website using cherrypy and jinja2 as a proof of concept before we begin a rewrite of our current site.  So maybe others have tried and could save us the attempt if in fact it is not feasible.
Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 per minute? Heck, it could do that from my netbook. 5,000 per minute? Yes, with a little load balancing. 5,000 per second would be a stretch.

Comment: Whep - yea I meant to say 5,000 per min.  Ok, good to know. Thanks!